# Answering questions that haven't been asked

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm a frequent user of Math SE and I've been working to understand something for the past week that I really struggled with. What's more is that I wasn't able to find a good thread on Math SE on this topic, and so I had to look through several textbooks and resources before getting a good grip on this. Is there any way for me to create a thread on Math SE for this, which might be helpful to students who're in the same position I was in? Is the best way to do this asking a question myself and then answering it, or is there a way to create a thread with just write-ups on topics (that people might find helpful) as well, not in answer to a particular question?